# How to position a widget at the bottom of a ScrollView contining a Column?

Tags: flutter

Using Flutter, I am trying to position a widget (a button) at the bottom of a `SingleChildScrollView`.

A specific requirement is that the button should at the bottom of the screen if the content of the `SingleChildScrollView` does not take the whole screen.

Here is what I tried:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
      Container(
        height: 1000,
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      // Expanded(
      //   child: Container(
      //     color: Colors.yellow,
      //   ),
      // ),
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.edit,
        ),
      ),
    ]));
  }
}
```

This gives the following result with various heights:

[image: scrollview-1]
[image: scrollview-2]

As expected, the button is positioned at the bottom of the `SingleChildScrollView` but not at the bottom of the screen. I tried to use a `Spacer` (or an `Expandable`) but this always fails with the following error:

> FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

**Edit**: this was not stated explicitly in my original question. The button should be only visible after scrolling if the view as a larger height than the display.

Comment: can you include the full widget tree from scaffold body. You can use button after the singleChildScrollVIew

Answer (score 0):

How about using the constarins of maxhight to the parent of singlechild scroll view..
try the below

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 75),//75 is the size of button
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 100,
                          color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 75,//size of button
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.edit,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: The button should be only visible after scrolling if the view as a larger height than the display. Sorry it was not stated explicitly in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it via

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 500,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),  
          ],
        ),),),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.edit,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
```

Comment: The button should be only visible after scrolling if the view as a larger height than the display. Sorry it was not stated explicitly in my original question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question by edit in original place so i can better answer you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Expected output]

Currently you have made the singleChildScrollView as the parent of all the remaining widgets including the Textbutton, Instead what you can do is make the column as the parent of all the remaining widgets and the singleChildScrollView and TextButton as a two separate children of this parent column as shown in the code.

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 500,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
          ),
          // You may add other widgets
        ],
      ),
    ),
    // The text Button Is out side of the singleChildScrollView
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: const Icon(
        Icons.edit,
      ),
    )
  ],
);}}
```

Comment: There is an overflow if the container height is large.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build this layout using a `LayoutBuilder`:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 1000,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.edit,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I am still interested in a simpler solution if it exists.